# MySql: check and remove duplicate rows

Tags: mysql, duplication

- How can I check if a table contains duplicate rows, with the same value of the couple  (date, time) ?
- How can I remove all but one row ?
- Id is a sequential number that I increment after every post, how can I restore it after removing a row ?

the table **tableTen** is:

```
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field     | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id        | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| symbol    | varchar(25) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| date      | date        | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| time      | time        | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Answer (score 5):

**1. How can I check if a table contains duplicate rows, with the same value of the couple (date, time) ?**

```
SELECT *  FROM db.table HAVING COUNT(symbol) > 1
```

**2. How can I remove all but one row ?**

a) If you want to keep the row with the lowest id value:

```
DELETE n1 FROM table n1, table n2 WHERE n1.id > n2.id AND n1.symbol= n2.symbol
```

b) If you want to keep the row with the highest id value:

```
DELETE n1 FROM table n1, table n2 WHERE n1.id < n2.id AND n1.symbol= n2.symbol
```

**3. Id is a sequential number that I increment after every post, how can I restore it after removing a row ?**

Please try http://befused.com/mysql/reset-auto-increment

Answer (score 1):

Your specification is unclear -- Do you want distinct values for the triple (symbol, date, time)?  Or just of (symbol)?  I will assume the former since the latter gets messier.

If there are a large number of dups, then this may be faster.

```
CREATE TABLE new LIKE tableTen;
INSERT INTO new
    SELECT DISTINCT MAX(id), symbol, date, time FROM tableTen
        GROUP BY             symbol, date, time;
RENAME TABLE tableTen TO old,
             new TO tableTen;
DROP TABLE old;
```

Caveat:  If you have `NULLs`, it may not work as expected.

Side issues:

- Your lack of a `PRIMARY KEY` is a no-no.
- Having all columns `NULLable` is rarely realistic.
- Splitting date and time into two separate columns *usually* leads to clumsy coding.